# Duplicate XML structure tag appear

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I'm trying to build a Serliazation for an XML structure the Goal is to achieve a tag with multiple children such as quantity, and I can achieve that by adding a subclass inside the structure, however, the node of the class is appearing as well the child nodes as a duplicate for Example:

The Goal is to Achieve this structure:

```
        <Quantity>
          <QuantityString>13686.37</QuantityString>
          <DataType>float</DataType>
          <UnitOfMeasure>KG</UnitOfMeasure>
        </Quantity>
        <Quantity>
          <QuantityString>13.69</QuantityString>
          <DataType>float</DataType>
          <UnitOfMeasure>TO</UnitOfMeasure>
        </Quantity>
```

My Result appeared as follows:

```
      <Quantity>
        <Quantity>
          <QuantityString>sample string 1</QuantityString>
          <DataType>sample string 2</DataType>
          <UnitOfMeasure>sample string 3</UnitOfMeasure>
        </Quantity>
        <Quantity>
          <QuantityString>sample string 1</QuantityString>
          <DataType>sample string 2</DataType>
          <UnitOfMeasure>sample string 3</UnitOfMeasure>
        </Quantity>
      </Quantity>
```

The First Quantity comes from the Class it self:

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonShopList
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Item", Order = 1)]
    public String ItemName{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Quantity", Order = 2)]
    public Quantity[] Quantity;
}

[DataContract]
public class Quantity
{
    [DataMember(Name = "QuantityString", Order = 1)]
    public String QuantityString { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "DataType", Order = 2)]
    public String DataType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "UnitOfMeasure", Order = 3)]
    public String UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just rename `Quantity` array field to `Quantities` which is true. Also I would use name `Value` instead of `QuantityString`

Comment: Can't I need to match this XML Structure.

Comment: So if your xml matches the required schema, what is the problem then?

Comment: it's not matched, in their XML they have Quantity one and two.. but in mine, i have one list which inside of it Quantity one and two. using a list caused duplicate tags how to avoid it.

Comment: Add following above public Quantity[] Quantity :  [XmlElement(ElementName = "Quantity")]  The code is defaulting to an array type that is creating two levels of tags.  Using XmlElement will eliminate one level of tag.

Comment: Did this but the tag disappeared now.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more of the code logic itself to get a better understanding your calling strategy.

Comment: what more logic I can share, this is using rest API, and I'm trying to build the DataContract to match what I have in the XML sent.